# Laravel check CSRF manually in controller

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, socket.io

I'm using Laravel 5.5. When I send POST request from laravel blade. Then everything is ok:

```
$.post({
    url: 'http://localhost/check',
    data: {
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN,  // I have CSRF token variable above.
        test: "it works"
    }
})
```

But I want to send that request with socket.io > node.js > laravel :

```
socket.emit('checkPost', { token: CSRF_TOKEN });
```

index.js

```
socket.on('checkPost', function (csrf) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost/check',
        form: {
            _token: csrf.token,
            test: "it works"
        }
    });
});
```

With ajax everything is ok. Here I got token missmatch. Why?

When I disable token verification in `VerifyCsrfToken` for /check route then node request works too.

How can I fix that? Maybe there is controller csrf check method? Then I'll check post csrf in controller.. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Does node.js forward the cookies as well?

Comment: @apokryfos nope, I think I understand. In node there is no any sessions from laravel yep?

Comment: The problem is that Laravel loads the session by reading the session cookie that the user sends. If the request goes directly via post then the cookies are sent correctly but if they go via a socket to node.js then the cookies are probably not sent at all. Therefore the request from node.js to laravel will appear to be a fresh request from a new user every time.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie is it good idea to send cookie session with socket?

Comment: The correct way to authenticate a user via sockets would probably be a token based approach like oauth or jwt. But those are probably a bit overkill for simple use cases. If it's a simple use case then just sending the cookies and having node forward them (doesn't even need to parse them) should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please write answer. I'll check it as answer

Comment: It's not really an answer, just a suggestion. If someone can offer a concrete solution then it's probably better. If not I'll go ahead and write something up.

Comment: maybe you could pass the CRSF token in the meta?

Comment: I have the feeling you're mixing up things... you're trying to prevent CSRF and actually making a CSRF... and also probably mixing  REST with event based communication.... basically I would go for .on('checkPost', ... emit and event).... that event would be intercepted from its handler and do stuff... I assume this because you're posting to localhost... If you need instead to access an external service you should definitely go for a POST API request... and in such case a oauth server in the middle will be needed to secure or auth the call.

Comment: check `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` which is responsible for CSRF tokens. You can reverse engineer that code to make it run in nodejs.

Comment: Can you add your code on how to verify the csrf token in controller (assuming that the validation is manually done without the use of middleware) Since I also need to verify the csrf token from websocket.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the underline before the token variable name. Laravel's token input name is "_token" not "token". you must write it this way:

```
socket.emit('checkPost', { _token: CSRF_TOKEN });
```

It's just a typo.

Hope this would help.